# angularjs : set min time dynamically for <input type='time'> not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set the minimum time dynamically to current time but its not working.Its not showing errors.where am i going wrong?

```js
$scope.mintime = new Date();
```

```html
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
  <span class="input-label" >Preferred Time</span>
  <input type="time" class="input-control" name="requestTime"  ng-model="request.time" ng-change="checktime();" min="{{mintime | date:'hh:mm a'}}" required>
</label>
```

Comment: Have you tried ngMin ?

Comment: how to use ngMin??...do i have to add the directive also?

Comment: Try this : `<input type="time" class="input-control" name="requestTime"  ng-model="request.time" ng-change="checktime();" ng-min="mintime" required>`

Comment: @Vincismique not working

Answer (score 2):

Try this : `min="{{mintime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}"`

It's just about format :)

Comment: I want to validate the time ,i want to set min to time format.

Comment: Have you tried `min="{{mintime | date:'yyyy-mm-dd'}}" `?

Comment: OK, didn't see that it's a "time" input, I edit the answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm">
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Preferred Time</span>
    <input  type="time" class="input-control" name="requestTime" ng-model="request.time" ng-change="checktime();" min="{{date | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}" required>
  </label>

  {{myForm.requestTime.$valid}}

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

angular.module('sampleApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date();
  })
```

Checkout the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/jzczzz40/

Otherwise you have to check the value in `ng-change`

Comment: sincei'm using angularjs validation i had to set the form to 'novalidate' attr.....so can you tell me how to do without it

Comment: you have to use `ng-form` and checkout the form is valid or not; updated the answer check it